# Is non-blocking algorithm also apply for insertion and deletion OR only for some condition like no available space/ no elements to consume

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking, java.util.concurrent

Some blogs mentioned that non-blocking algorithm Data Structures will not block calling threads if no space/element to add/consume. They immediately return with Exception or null. But nowhere I have not found How insertion/deletion works in non-blocking algorithms.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/LocalAsyncLoadingCache.java for a fully non-blocking cache/map implementation and you will see how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might take different operations when condition is not satisfied. There are four typical forms:

- throw exeption
- return a special value
- block
- time out

For non-blocking implemention, the first two might happen.

Refer the doc of [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html):

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue
>   to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to
>   become available in the queue when storing an element.
>
> BlockingQueue methods come in four forms, with different ways of
>   handling operations that cannot be satisfied immediately, but may be
>   satisfied at some point in the future: one throws an exception, the
>   second returns a special value (either null or false, depending on the
>   operation), the third blocks the current thread indefinitely until the
>   operation can succeed, and the fourth blocks for only a given maximum
>   time limit before giving up. These methods are summarized in the
>   following table:

```
         Throws exception   Special value   Blocks           Times out
Insert   add(e)             offer(e)        put(e)           offer(e, time, unit)
Remove   remove()           poll()          take()           poll(time, unit)
Examine  element()          peek()          not applicable   not applicable
```